# Android Calendar like Expedia

Tags: android, user-interface, calendar, components

I'm on building application,

What am trying to do is building calendar like expedia app.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: img]

Do you guys any idea what component should i use from base and what event should i use when select several box on that.

Comment: did u get a solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either chose to use the 4.0 calendarView backported to 2.1 ([project here](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview)), or implement yourself your own calendarView extending a ViewGroup. This is not as hard as you can think :)